# how to create idle/uptime metric for dataproc cluster with stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-cloud-dataproc, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I would like to create an idle or uptime metric for all dataproc clusters I am running, and from what I've seen in stackdriver, I was not able to do so.
My scenario is that I have timed dataproc jobs that run daily and after the jobs are done I delete the cluster.
I would like to create an alert via email if there are idle dataproc clusters that do nothing for an hour or a dataproc cluster uptime is more then 24 (or even 20) hours.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a 3 items in your question I'd like to address separately:

1. About alerting on idle metric: Dataproc does not expose such a metric and I will file a feature request for us to add one. In the mean time, you can approximate idleness by detecting when this metric: `dataproc.googleapis.com/cluster/yarn/containers` goes down to 0 for an hour or so.
2. Regarding cluster being idle for an hour or alive for 24 hours. This can be automated through Dataproc via [Scheduled Deletion](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/scheduled-deletion) feature: `gcloud beta dataproc clusters create ... --max-age=24h --max-idle=1h`
3. About daily jobs. I think here you could sidestep questions #1 and #2 entirely and leverage [Workflow Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/overview) to manage cluster creation, teardown, and job execution. If your automation is through Api clients or you need to pass different parameters on each invocation [InstantiateInline](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.regions.workflowTemplates/instantiateInline) method will do the trick

Comment: I'm aware on both the idle and cluster alive API's but they are in the beta java client (I'm using non-beta client), so I will wait until the code move outside of beta, and the solution I implemented was done before Workflow was out, so for now its not a preferred solution.
bullet #1 will do the trick, until I will be able to use the idle API.
thanks!